# What is the difference between the two versions of functions

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

Can some one explain what is the difference between these two code blocks? Why would we ever need the first type when second one is more concise.

First

```
var Utility;
(function (Utility) {
    var Func = (function () {
        function Func(param1, param2) {
            var self = this;
            this.Owner = param2;
        }
        return Func;
    })();
    Utility.Func = Func;
})(Utility || (Utility = {}));
```

Second:

```
var Utility;
(function (Utility) {
    Utility.Func = function (param1, param2) {
            var self = this;
            this.Owner = param2;
        }
})(Utility || (Utility = {}));
```

context: First version was code generated by typescript compiler and I am trying to understand why did it generate the first instead of a simpler second.

Comment: Personally, I don't get the purpose of either of these as there appears to be no actual benefit to any of the three closures in the code you've shown so all they do is add unnecessary complexity.  This achieves the same and is much simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wy37vvw3/

Comment: This is code generated by typescript compiler. First version was generated and I am trying to understand why did it generate the first instead of a simpler second.

Comment: Next time put that extra context into the question since that's really what your question is.  More closures means more places to put private variables (even though none are being used in these examples).  So perhaps the TypeScript code generator has cases where it will use some private variables in these closures so it puts them there for the general case in case it wants to use them.  The first just has more places to put private variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between the code blocks is that the first has a function scope around the code that creates the `Func` function. The only reason to do that would be to create a scope where you can declare variables that would not be available in the outer scope:

```
var Utility;
(function (Utility) {
    var Func = (function () {

        var x; // a variable in the inner scope

        function Func(param1, param2) {
            var self = this;
            this.Owner = param2;
        }
        return Func;
    })();

    // the variable x is not reachable from code here

    Utility.Func = Func;
})(Utility || (Utility = {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I see they are the same, in both cases you are defining the function and making it as a member of Utility, the calling it.
Add to it, no scope differences, no context differences, no difference really.
I think it's a matter of preference nothing more.

But, I can see one potential difference, in case the very inside one was a `async` function call, there might be a difference , since `Utility.Func` will end up having `undefined` as a value, which is a very big problem with the first one, but I doubt the person writing it will not notice.